# React: connect-react-router: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have problem configuring connect-react-router. I keep getting `Error: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"`.
I'm using react, redux-toolkit, typescript and using this react [template](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate-cra-template) as base. I have seen all the questions and answers related to this error and tried, but nothing worked. I'm using `history` with `version 4.10.1` Here is my code, can someone help me to point out where is the issue?

***reducers.ts***

```
/**
 * Combine all reducers in this file and export the combined reducers.
 */

import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import { InjectedReducersType } from 'utils/types/injector-typings';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
/**
 * Merges the main reducer with the router state and dynamically injected reducers
 */
export function createReducer(injectedReducers: InjectedReducersType = {}) {
  // Initially we don't have any injectedReducers, so returning identity function to avoid the error
  if (Object.keys(injectedReducers).length === 0) {
    return state => state;
  } else {
    return combineReducers({
      router: connectRouter(history),
      ...injectedReducers,
    });
  }
}

export { history };
```

***configureStore.ts***

```
/**
 * Create the store with dynamic reducers
 */

import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createInjectorsEnhancer } from 'redux-injectors';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';

import { createReducer, history } from './reducers';

export function configureAppStore() {
  const reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);
  const connectedRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
  const { run: runSaga } = sagaMiddleware;

  // Create the store with saga, router middleware
  const middlewares = [sagaMiddleware, connectedRouterMiddleware];

  const enhancers = [
    createInjectorsEnhancer({
      createReducer,
      runSaga,
    }),
  ];

  const customizedDefaultMiddleware = getDefaultMiddleware({
    serializableCheck: false,
  });

  return configureStore({
    reducer: createReducer(),
    middleware: [...customizedDefaultMiddleware, ...middlewares],
    devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
    enhancers,
  });
}
```

And in my App file, I'm using it via Provider like this:

```
/**
 *
 * App
 *
 * This component is the skeleton around the actual pages, and should only
 * contain code that should be seen on all pages. (e.g. navigation bar)
 */

import * as React from 'react';

import {
  AppLayout,
  AppStyleProvider,
  AppThemeProvider,
  ContextProvider,
} from './@app';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router';
import AuthRoutes from './@app/utility/AuthRoutes';
import { CssBaseline } from '@material-ui/core';
import { history } from '../store/reducers';
import { HelmetProvider } from 'react-helmet-async';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureAppStore } from '../store/configureStore';

const store = configureAppStore();

export function App() {
  return (
    <ContextProvider>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppThemeProvider>
          <AppStyleProvider>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
              <AuthRoutes>
                <CssBaseline />
                <HelmetProvider>
                  <AppLayout />
                </HelmetProvider>
              </AuthRoutes>
            </ConnectedRouter>
          </AppStyleProvider>
        </AppThemeProvider>
      </Provider>
    </ContextProvider>
  );
}
```

I didn't get any compilation errors, but when I run the app I get `Error: Could not find router reducer in state tree, it must be mounted under "router"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is honestly a very strange setup that you have here.  You initially create the store with no reducers and inject them all after the fact.

Your `createReducer()` function is called by `configureAppStore()` without any arguments.  When this happens, you are returning a reducer which does not have the required `router` property.  Why?  Your app will always get initialized without a `router` reducer.

```
export function createReducer(injectedReducers: InjectedReducersType = {}) {
  // Initially we don't have any injectedReducers, so returning identity function to avoid the error
  if (Object.keys(injectedReducers).length === 0) {
    return (state) => state;
  } else {
    return combineReducers({
      router: connectRouter(history),
      ...injectedReducers
    });
  }
}
```

I fixed the error by removing this condition.

```
export function createReducer(injectedReducers: InjectedReducersType = {}) {
  return combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...injectedReducers
  });
}
```

Comment: Yes removing the condition worked! I got the point